# OOP - Problema con return main() y un ciclo anidado

Tags: c++, class

Tengo el código siguiente funcionando mal. Quisiera que tras elegir alguna de las opciones 1 y 2 del submenú, el programa regrese al menú principal. Coloqué `return main();`, que hasta antes de aplicar clases funcionaba bien, pero ahora no jala el programa.

¿Sabrán cómo solucionarlo? Gracias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
int opcion, opcion1;
  void menu();
  void submenu();
};

void A::menu(){
    do{
        cout << "1. Registro" << endl;
        cout << "0. Salir" << endl;
        cin >> opcion;
        if(opcion==1){
            submenu();
        }else if (opcion==0){
            
        }else{
            cout << "Opción inválida" << endl;
        }
    }while(opcion!=0);
}

void A::submenu(){
    do{
        cout << "1. Taxonomía" << endl;
        cout << "2. Categoría" << endl;
        cout << "0. Salir" << endl;
        cin >> opcion1;
        if(opcion1==1){
            cout << "Taxonomía de la planta" << endl;
        }else if(opcion1==2){
            cout << "Categoría de la planta" << endl;
        }else if (opcion1==0){
            
        }else{
            cout << "Opción inválida" << endl;
        }
        return main();
    }while(opcion1!=0);
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
    
    A a;
    a.menu();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El estandar de C++ dice [que la funcion `main` no se puede usar dentro de un programa](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3) (Que es lo que tu haces con el `return main();`). Asi que tu programa cae en comportamiento indefinido. Puede funcionar, puede fallar, todo vale.

Comment: @Pablochaches Ya veo. Al final, la solución era tan simple como colocar ```return menu();``` XD

Comment: @ArturoGarcíaFlores ¡Ponlo como respuesta! Y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu declaración de función retorna void o sea ningun valor. Usar la línea return main() no tendrá efecto intenta así:

main();

Sin el return